# store $.each result into array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I have `$.each` get the Facebook friends list.

Here is the `$.each` code

```
$.each(response.data, function(index,friend) {
    alert(friend.name + ' has id:' + friend.id);
}
```

now how I can store this data in array to be like this array

```
friends = [
    { "name": "John"  , "id": "1" },
    { "name": "Anna"  , "id": "2" },
    { "name": "Peter" , "id": "3" }
];
```

Comment: `var friends = response.data` ?

Answer (score 5):

`$.map` is like `$.each`, but it returns an array of return values from the function:

```
var friends = $.map(response.data, function(index, friend) {
    return {
        name: friend.name,
        id: friend.id
    };
});
```

Although… since you appear to already have an array of objects with those properties, why not just use that?

Comment: Great ... now how I can parse it?

Comment: @ManMann: Parse which part?

Comment: now I am saving this array in the Iphone local storage. now I want to parse this array in another page

Comment: @ManMann: How are you saving it? As JSON?

Comment: no .. I just save it as 1 object like this localStorage.setItem('user_list', flist);

Comment: @ManMann: Use `localStorage.getItem('user_list')`?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35634/discussion-between-man-mann-and-minitech)

Answer (score 2):

Try `var friends = response.data;`.

You may get extra fields, but the response.data already is an array of objects with `name` and `id` fields.  It may contain other fields as well.

So while you can process `response.data` with `$.each` or `$.map` to eliminate the other fields, depending on your application it may be possible to use `response.data` as is, without further processing.